# How to add a ball over the line and move the ball with each click in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create this ball moving. So each click it's supposed to add a ball to the end of the line from the right and as the animation still runs the ball will move to the left until it disappears. So if I click the button 5 times I should have 5 balls moving at the same time but the first will go first and follow by the rest of the balls. And the distance should depend on when the button is clicked.

Here's what I have gotten so far.

```
// RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||  
        function( callback ) {
            return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

var loop = 400;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawALine() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(10, 10);
    context.lineTo(400, 10);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawABall(positionX) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(positionX, 10, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
}

function clearScreen() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function animloop() {
    loop = loop - 1;
    init = requestAnimFrame(animloop);

    clearScreen();
    drawALine();
    drawABall(loop);
}

jQuery('#addBall').click(function() {
    animloop();
    drawABall(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/z5VwL/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of balls

```
var balls = [];
```

and at every click you can add a new `Ball` object to the list:

```
jQuery('#addBall').click(function() {
    balls.push(new Ball());
});
```

The `Ball` object looks like this:

```
function Ball() {
    this.pos = 400;
    this.render = function() {
        this.pos -= 1;      

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.pos, 10, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        context.stroke();
    };
}
```

So now your `animLoop` function looks like this:

```
function animloop() {
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);

    clearScreen();
    drawALine();
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        balls[i].render();
    }
}
```

I've made an **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5VwL/7/)** for this.